# xml XPathSelectElements => to string type

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xpath

I have the following XML structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xml>
  <root>
    <Item>
      <taxids>
        <string>330</string>
        <string>374</string>
        <string>723</string>
        <string>1087</string>
        <string>1118</string>
        <string>1121</string>
      </taxids>
    </Item>
  </root>
</xml>
```

I need to get all the string nodes from the xml file to a string variable, like this:

```
var query = from ip in doc.XPathSelectElements("xml/root/Item")
            where ip.XPathSelectElement("taxid").Value == "723"
            select ip.XPathSelectElements("taxids").ToString();
```

But I am getting the following in one row of the variable `query`:

```
"System.Xml.XPath.XPathEvaluator+<EvaluateIterator>d__0`1[System.Xml.Linq.XElement]"
```

I want to get a string like this:

```
  <taxids><string>330</string><string>374</string><string>723</string><string>1087</string><string>1118</string><string>1121</string></taxids>
```

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you something like:

```
var values = from ids in doc.XPathSelectElements("/xml/root/Item/taxids")
                     from id in ids.XPathSelectElements("string")
                     where id.Value.Contains("723")
                     select ids.ToString();

var result = string.Join("", values);
```

The `value` variable will contain all the taxids, which have at least one `string` child with value `723`.

Another variant, which doesn't use XPath for the children checking:

```
var values = from ids in doc.XPathSelectElements("/xml/root/Item/taxids")
                     from id in ids.Elements("string")
                     where id.Value.Contains("723")
                     select ids.ToString();

var result = string.Join("\n", values);
```

Comment: It is not the purpose to get the first. i only gave an example. but this wont work. You are doing the same as me. or am i wrong?

Comment: I have updated my answer. This will now work. I've checked it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
<xml>
<root>
<Item>
<taxids>
<string>330</string>
<string>374</string>
<string>723</string>
<string>1087</string>
<string>1118</string>
<string>1121</string>
</taxids>
</Item>
</root>
</xml>");

var query = doc.XPathSelectElement("xml/root/Item/taxids");

Console.WriteLine(query);
```

Comment: Hi. but i need to do a linq query so i can filter the results.. should this work also?

Comment: @Ozkan, What do you mean? It works as you wrote in your question? Please update your question with detailed information.